# Loading huge text files for neural machine translation with Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

In PyTorch, I have written a dataset loading class for loading 2 text files as source and targets, for neural machine translation purpose. Each file has 93577946 lines, and each of them allocates 8GB memory on Hard Disc.

The class is as the following:

```
class LoadUniModal(Dataset):
    sources = []
    targets = []
    maxlen = 0
    lengths = []

    def __init__(self, src, trg, src_vocab, trg_vocab):
        self.src_vocab = src_vocab
        self.trg_vocab = trg_vocab

        with codecs.open(src, encoding="utf-8") as f:
            for line in f:
                tokens = line.replace("\n", "").split()
                self.maxlen = max(self.maxlen, len(tokens))
                self.sources.append(tokens)
        with codecs.open(trg, encoding="utf-8") as f:
            for line in f:
                tokens = line.replace("\n", "").split()
                self.maxlen = max(self.maxlen, len(tokens))
                self.targets.append(tokens)
                self.lengths.append(len(tokens)+2)

    # Overrride to give PyTorch access to any image on the dataset
    def __getitem__(self, index):

        # Source sentence processing
        tokens = self.sources[index]
        ntokens = [self.src_vocab['<START>']]
        for a in range(self.maxlen):
            if a <= (len(tokens) - 1):
                if tokens[a] in self.src_vocab.keys():
                    ntokens.append(self.src_vocab[tokens[a]])
                else:
                    ntokens.append(self.src_vocab['<UNK>'])
            elif a == len(tokens):
                ntokens.append(self.src_vocab['<END>'])
            elif a > len(tokens):
                ntokens.append(self.src_vocab['<PAD>'])

        source = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(ntokens)).long()

        # Target sentence processing
        tokens = self.targets[index]
                ntokens = [self.trg_vocab['<START>']]
                for a in range(self.maxlen):
                        if a <= (len(tokens) - 1):
                                if tokens[a] in self.trg_vocab.keys():
                                        ntokens.append(self.trg_vocab[tokens[a]])
                                else:
                                        ntokens.append(self.trg_vocab['<UNK>'])
                        elif a == len(tokens):
                                ntokens.append(self.trg_vocab['<END>'])
                        elif a > len(tokens):
                                ntokens.append(self.trg_vocab['<PAD>'])

                target = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(ntokens)).long()

        length = self.lengths[index]

        return [0], source, target, length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sources)
```

I use the class in order to load dataset as follows:

```
def load_text_train_data(train_dir, src_vocab, trg_vocab, lang_pair, batch_size):

        tpl = ast.literal_eval(lang_pair)
        slang = tpl[1]
        tlang = tpl[2]

        strain_file = os.path.join(train_dir, "train"+slang)
        ttrain_file = os.path.join(train_dir, "train"+tlang)

        data_iter = LoadUniModal(strain_file, ttrain_file, src_vocab, trg_vocab)
        data_iter = DataLoader(data_iter, batch_size=batch_size)

        return data_iter
```

When I am trying to load the data, I get memory error.

How would it be possible to load the data without memory problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't give you an error unless you load the entire data in memory at once. One suggestion I want to give you is: don't pad all sentences to a maximum length. In machine translation data, in general, sentence lengths vary a lot.

Also, you can try smaller mini-batches of size `x` (ex., 32, 64) which your memory can afford. Only pad the elements of the current mini-batch and move to cuda tensor and then pass it to your model. Hopefully, it will solve your problem.